# Disable pagination in django-tables2?

Tags: django, tags, django-tables2

In [django-tables2](/questions/tagged/django-tables2) I have a table which I do not want paginated. I have not specified pagination, as shown in the docs:

```
table.paginate(page=request.GET.get('page', 1), per_page=25)
```

The tables still paginate, presumably by default. The `RequestConfig` class docstring says to pass a false value for paginate to disable pagination but I'm fuzzy on it.  Here are options I've tried in my view class:

```
my_table.paginate = False
RequestConfig(request).configure(my_table, paginate=False)
RequestConfig(request).configure(my_table).paginate(False)
RequestConfig(request).configure(my_table, {table.paginate:False})
RequestConfig(request).configure(my_table, {paginate:False})
RequestConfig(request).configure(my_table, {"paginate":False})
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You want to do:

```
RequestConfig(request, paginate=False).configure(my_table)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with class based views of Django, just override the get_table_pagination method in your view class and get_caption_display method in table class:

```
class YourView(SingleTableMixin, generic.TemplateView):
    def get_table_pagination(self):
        return False
```

In your table class,

```
class YourTable(Table):
    def get_caption_display(self):
        return False
```